# Running java applet with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, applet, japplet

I've been trying to convert my applet codebase over to using gradle. However I cannot seem to find a way to run the applet.

Does anyone know of a way to run applets with gradle?

Comment: Running it for testing or as an application? Applets are components so they can be added to JFrames (or others) to be displayed as a GUI application. Also their used to be an applet viewer application but I think that might have died a few versions back.

Comment: @cjstehno not for deployment no, just for testing

Answer (score 1):

I had the same task and was trying to launch `appletviewer` via Gradle. It would be easy to do with `Exec`, but we had to specify `java.security.policy`. The only solution worked for me was the following.

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
task runApplet(type: Exec) {
   workingDir '../build/demo/'
   if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
     commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "appletviewer -J\"-Djava.security.policy=java.policy.applet\" applet.html"
   } else {
     commandLine 'sh', '-c', "appletviewer -J\"-Djava.security.policy=java.policy.applet\" applet.html"
   }
}
```